# No shipping with paypal API v2

Tags: vue.js, paypal, nuxt.js

I'm trying to disable delivery as explained in the documentation but it doesn't work.
[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wAn3O.png)

Doc : https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-order_application_context

```js
 createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: "global description",
                  items: [
                    {
                      name: "aaa",
                      quantity: 1,
                      unit_amount: { currency_code: "EUR", value: 10 }
                    },
                    {
                      name: "bbb",
                      quantity: 2,
                      unit_amount: { currency_code: "EUR", value: 10 }
                    }
                  ],
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "EUR",
                    value: 30,
                    breakdown: {
                      item_total: {
                        currency_code: "EUR",
                        value: 30
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  order_application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
                  }
                }
              ]
            });
```

Same issue with :

```
application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
                  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to put application_context outside of purchase_units like this

```js
 createOrder: (data, actions) => {
            return actions.order.create({
              purchase_units: [
                {
                  description: "global description",
                  items: [
                    {
                      name: "aaa",
                      quantity: 1,
                      unit_amount: { currency_code: "EUR", value: 10 }
                    },
                    {
                      name: "bbb",
                      quantity: 2,
                      unit_amount: { currency_code: "EUR", value: 10 }
                    }
                  ],
                  amount: {
                    currency_code: "EUR",
                    value: 30,
                    breakdown: {
                      item_total: {
                        currency_code: "EUR",
                        value: 30
                      }
                    }
                  },                  
                }
              ],
              application_context: {
                    shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
              }
            });
           },
```

Comment: Oops my mistake . 
Thank you

Comment: @Jattion how did you know this??